# Snackbar и проблемы с его реализацией

Tags: java, android, material-design, snackbar

Я добавил эту библиотеку `com.android.support:design:27.1.1` в свое андроид-приложение. Необходимо при возникновении `NullPointerException` показывать пользователю `Snackbar`. Как я могу показать `Snackbar` в блоке `catch`?

Comment: Ну... Типа Snackbar.show() как-то так. Кажется, в вопросе не хватает более подробного описания ваших затруднений.

Comment: Рассматривая примеры создания `Snackbar` везде его использовали при нажатии на кнопку, при его иницилизации первым аргументом передавался объект класса `view`. В слушателе нажатия это просто сделать. А по другому никак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Hello", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
```

вы кажется навичок и скорее всего вы не поймете откуда взять view. Поищите в параметрах метода. Если нету то придется главный контейнер (без разницы Linearlayout или RelativeLayout или другое) преобразавать в View. Примерно так:
View v = (View) findViewById (R.id.main)

Comment: Вау и правда, спасибо!